# How to reimport CMYK PDF into Adobe (Illustrator/Photshop etc) after Negative Decode [ 0 1 ]

Tags: pdf, adobe, ghostscript, postscript, cmyk

I have a pdf created by InDesign that I want to re-create in postscript.

The following script creates me my (simple) pdf as expected using the negative Decode Array.  Looks great in pdf readers (as expected) however, when I re-open it in Illustrator or other Adobe products the JPG turns negative.

```
  << /PageSize [419.528 595.276] >> setpagedevice 
    % [ W x H ] 
    /DeviceCMYK setcolorspace 
    % Page 1 

    %
    % Set the Original to be the top left
    %
    0 595.276 translate 
    1 -1 scale 
    gsave 


    %% Images when flipped to draw correctly are scaled UPWARDS 
%% so you need to move the x,y position to the bottom left

-1.44 621.714330709 translate % Bottom Left Cordinates

% unset the mirror or the image will be flipped!
1 -1 scale 

% scale the image
438.000944882 657.119055118 scale  %%% Need to work out size and width into Units


/Image1File (cmyk_image.jpg) (r) file /DCTDecode filter  def

/Image1
{
<<
  /ImageType 1
  /Width 1825
  /Height 2738
  /ImageMatrix [1825 0 0 -2738 0 2738]
  /BitsPerComponent 8
  /Decode [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0] % can either be 1 0 or 0 1
  /DataSource Image1File
>>
} bind def

/DeviceCMYK setcolorspace
Image1 image

% Reset to previous X and Y ( line 13 )
grestore 
gsave

showpage
```

I understand this is due to Adobe's way of inverting its decode values but I haven't came across an actual solution where an external library can create a pdf which can be reused in Adobe's porgrams.

Attached is the JPG in question.

[cmyk_image](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/2a2c1929313cd128318c777ebfc3f84520150520164258/ea6a905d99414ca01066a49964fc172220150520164258/e49944)

Command to execute to above script.ps

```
gs -o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress input.ps
```

[CMYK image and Issue PDF.zip](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/c3e57ca99cd4a5541cf116f28a9bac7720150521144511/55f8e50755d85480f2ceb51238cd78cc20150521144511/c13c53)

Comment: Could you also provide the PDF file you get that doesn't work correctly? Without a working installation of GhostScript I can't redo your command, but I'd be happy to look at the PDF file.

Comment: Done - updated my post to include this.  Thanks

Comment: Well the PDF views correctly in Adobe Acrobat Pro, which is obviously, an Adobe program. If Illustrator can't view this correctly then I'd be inclined to say its an Illustrator problem, which you should probably report to Adobe as a bug. I presume its the inverted Decode array causing a problem. You could solve this by putting the inversion into a procedural data source for your image, instead of using the file filter directly.

Comment: FWIW the problem may be that the JPEG file contains a CMYKLab ICC profile which, obviously, is not going to be applied by the simple use of DCTDecode. Also for reasons which now escape me, my own JPEG decoder looks for a APP marker segment (in this case an APPE) with the string 'Adobe' and then applies two different colour transforms depending on the 11th byte of that segment. Neither transform is 'correct' however. [Later] this appears to be (partially) documented in Adobe technical note 5114. I suspect that the value '2' requires some kind of extra treatment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fully agree with the points raised by David above, in particular the fact that you can't use Illustrator as a general PDF editing application.

However, since this *is* a programming question... Here is the code modified as hinted at in my comment above. This uses a procedural data source to invert the data as it is read. This obviates the need for an 'unusual' Decode array which I presume means it will work with Illustrator (I don't have a copy and so cannot check).

```
  << /PageSize [419.528 595.276] >> setpagedevice 
    % [ W x H ] 
    /DeviceCMYK setcolorspace 
    % Page 1 

    %
    % Set the Original to be the top left
    %
    0 595.276 translate 
    1 -1 scale 
    gsave 


    %% Images when flipped to draw correctly are scaled UPWARDS 
%% so you need to move the x,y position to the bottom left

-1.44 621.714330709 translate % Bottom Left Cordinates

% unset the mirror or the image will be flipped!
1 -1 scale 

% scale the image
438.000944882 657.119055118 scale  %%% Need to work out size and width into Units


/Image1File (d:/temp/cmyk_image.jpg) (r) file /DCTDecode filter  def

/Image1
{
<<
  /ImageType 1
  /Width 1825
  /Height 2738
  /ImageMatrix [1825 0 0 -2738 0 2738]
  /BitsPerComponent 8
  /ColorTransform 1
%  /Decode [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0] % can either be 1 0 or 0 1
  /Decode [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1] % can either be 1 0 or 0 1
%  /DataSource Image1File
  /DataSource {
Image1File 1825 string readstring pop
0 1 1824 {
1 index exch
dup 2 index exch get 255 exch sub put
} for
}
>>
} bind def

/DeviceCMYK setcolorspace
Image1 image

% Reset to previous X and Y ( line 13 )
grestore 
gsave

showpage
```

Comment: Holy Moley KenS, it works!  Thank you so much, this is AMAZING!  I'll look into this more to understand it better but fantastic!  Definately answered my question and looks great in Illustrator :D

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer as it pointed me in the right direction! I have a slightly different use case (CMYK-JPEG included in TCPDF-generated PDF). All common PDF readers would show the expected result, except Illustrator. I ended up negating the CMYK-JPEG (with Imagick) and changed the Decode Array to [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]. It now works in every common PDF reader AND in Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give an exact answer on your question, but I'll try anyway. In short, I would vote that this be logged as a bug against Adobe Illustrator and that this is the only possible answer on your question.

I opened your PDF file and it looks absolutely perfect, nothing wrong with it. Apple Preview, Adobe Acrobat DC, Adobe Photoshop CC 2014 all open it correctly and show the image correctly. The only application I find that behaves incorrectly is Adobe Illustrator (I tested the latest CC 2014 version so we can assume it's *all* versions of Illustrator).

In truth, you could even argue whether this is a bug in Illustrator or something that is simply not supported. Illustrator - contrary to popular belief - **is not** a PDF editor, nor does it support the completeness of the PDF specification. It is also not the case that the file format used by Illustrator is PDF; at best it's a subset of PDF and all truth be told Illustrator plays a very dirty trick to ensure roundtripping and to ensure it will always be able to use a PDF file it exported.

So:

- I don't believe your statement "or other Adobe applications" is true or is still true (it's entirely possible that older version of Photoshop for example had the same problem).
- I don't believe there is something wrong with your PDF file; there's something wrong with Illustrator (and with you believing you can use Illustrator to open any random PDF file without degradation :-)).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  To be honest - this whole 'issue' came down to my designer stating that in his workflow for other PDFs (if they contained EPSs), he would open it in Illustrator and edit it there.  Now I assumed that others would do this and even end printers. But I could be firm and state that these PDFs can't be used in illustrator.

Comment: Continued: I completely understand that this may be an illustrator bug - I had seen this issue in their forums but not how to fix it (if there is even a way) hence why I came here.  
So with your thoughts I will re-question the designer regarding their workflow and I have also raised a question in Adobe forums and see what they say.

Comment: Using Illustrator as a PDF editor is a very common practice but it has inherent dangers. There are real PDF editors that incur much less risk (such as Enfocus PitStop for example) but many people just use what they have (PitStop isn't inexpensive).

Comment: Since Illustrator also has capabilities beyond what PDF supports (brushes, gradient meshes, filters), I'd not call its native format a *subset* of PDF. All of its private info is encoded in a data chunk inside an otherwise valid PDF; and it's this that Illy scans for, and uses, when you open an "Illustrator editable" PDF. The 'real' PDF data is then simply ignored.